# My game in Meteor is sometimes laggy, sometimes not

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I made a simple shooting game in Meteor.  I'm still pretty new with Javascript, so I'm quite sure my code isn't the most efficient.

Anyway, everything works great on localhost (of course), and it seems okay for the most part when I deploy.  However, there are times where there will be a ton of lag and the client won't catch up for up to 30 seconds.  The canvas updates every 10ms on the client, and 100ms on the server.

Here's the game:
http://yujiangtham.com/jfleet/

Source:
https://github.com/ytham/jfleet

I'm not sure where to start with debugging this.  Could it be because:

a) Mongodb is not built for so many rapid read/writes?

b) Something somewhere is lagging and causing some sort of cascading lag?

c) Updating so many HTML elements on the canvas is causing the client to lag?

I'm honestly quite stumped.  Any pointers in the right direction would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, to clarify... the game uses Meteor so it can simultaneously support as many number of players on the page playing cooperatively, and thus from my understanding, everything requires database writes so that the status of the game is synced to all players in real(ish)-time.  Let me know if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Dig your problem down before ask and make one question for each problem.

Comment: @vinipsmaker this is not 3 separate questions.  I'm asking for help on where to start digging.  Thanks.

Comment: For the three tecnologies, I only have enough experience in MongoDB. You can use [MongoDB utilities](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/monitoring/#utilities) to understand the performance on your application. You can create [indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/) to improve the performance and [shard](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) to split the work among several servers.

Comment: @vinipsmaker great, thank you.  That's actually very helpful & gives me some ideas!

Answer (score 1):

So, I talked to a friend who had gone through something previously.  Basically, the way to solve this is to not write so often to the database.  It just can't handle that many writes in such a short period.

Basically, the way he told me to do this is by having the client and server compute all movement vectors separately.  From there, the client and server should both predict where each sprite should be, and then have them compare every 200ms or so.  Any differences should be overwritten by the server and written to the database.  That data is then sent back to the client and overwrites any difference.  I haven't actually implemented this yet since it requires a little bit of fancy math, but hopefully I'll get around to it soon enough...